# Refactor for supplier classes

Tags: java, spring

I'm looking to refactor two supplier classes as they both have very similar code. One provides and ArrayList and the other a Map. They are sorted in the configuration folder but I'm not sure thats the correct place. They both load data from a text file sorted in the project folder, which doesn't feel right to me.

[image: Project Structure]

The two supplier classes are:

```
@Component
public class ModulusWeightTableSupplier implements Supplier<List>{

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(CDLBankDetailsValidator.class);

    private static final String MODULUS_WEIGHT_TABLE = "AccountModulus_Weight_Table.txt";

    @Override
    public List<ModulusWeightTableEntry> get(){

        LOGGER.debug("Attempting to load modulus weight table " + MODULUS_WEIGHT_TABLE);
        final List<ModulusWeightTableEntry> modulusWeightTable = new ArrayList<>();

        try{
            final InputStream in = new FileInputStream(MODULUS_WEIGHT_TABLE);
            final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                final String[] fields = line.split("\\s+");
                modulusWeightTable.add(new ModulusWeightTableEntry(fields));
            }
            LOGGER.debug("Modulus weight table loaded");
            br.close();
        }
        catch (final IOException e) {
            throw new BankDetailsValidationRuntimeException("An error occurred loading the modulus weight table or sort code substitution table", e);
        }
        return modulusWeightTable;
    }
}
```

and

```
@Component
public class SortCodeSubstitutionTableSupplier implements Supplier<Map> {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(CDLBankDetailsValidator.class);

    private static final String SORT_CODE_SUBSTITUTION_TABLE = "SCSUBTAB.txt";

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> get() {

        LOGGER.debug("Attempting to load sort code substitution table " + SORT_CODE_SUBSTITUTION_TABLE);
        final Map<String, String> sortCodeSubstitutionTable = new HashMap<>();

        try {
            final InputStream in = new FileInputStream(SORT_CODE_SUBSTITUTION_TABLE);
            final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                final String[] fields = line.split("\\s+");
                sortCodeSubstitutionTable.put(fields[0], fields[1]);
            }
            LOGGER.debug("Sort code substitution table loaded");
            br.close();
        }
        catch (final IOException e) {
            throw new BankDetailsValidationRuntimeException("An error occurred loading the sort code substitution table", e);
        }

        return sortCodeSubstitutionTable;
    }
}
```

Both classes have a lot of duplicate code. I'm trying to work out the best way to refactor them.

Answer (score 2):

So your current code loads some configuration from textual files. Maybe best solution for this would be to go with properties or yaml files. This is most common approach for loading configuration data from external files.

Good starting point would be Spring Boot documentation for externalized configuration which provides information on how to use both properies and yaml files for loading configuration data in your application.

Comment: +1, pretty much both `get()` can be changed to use bean configuration properties (https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot). The trade-off here being that you wouldn't be able to just swap out the file and see changes. For that, he might use something like `@RefreshScope` and have the supplier be refreshable settings beans.

Comment: I think configuration properties could work for the Sort Code Substitution Table but the Modulus weight table comes to us in a .txt format direct from the banks. We wouldn't want to convert it as it would greatly increase the chance of errors being introduced.

Comment: *We wouldn't want to convert it as it would greatly increase the chance of errors being introduced.* Well, that's what tests are for ;) Surely you already have a test case for parsing the text file as-is, so it would only need to be extended. If you don't trust Spring and `spEL` enough for this purpose, you might just do it with plain ol' `java.util.Properties`. As a tradeoff, you'd have a much cleaner codebase.